# How to execute multiple json objects stored in file object

Tags: python, json

I have a text file which contain multiple json objects. Each json object have the followed structure:

```
{"api":{"results": 20, "teams":[{"team_id":123456,"name":"Lyon"}]}} 
{"api":{"results":20,"teams":[{"team_id":234567,"name":"Paris Saint Germain"}]}}
```

In above example i give example of two json objects. I want to extract some data from each json object.
 While i am trying to open and extract the necessary data

```
f = open(path/file.txt, "r+")
b = json.loads(f)
```

I get an error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 6205 (char 6204)
```

All day I tried to find solution to solve the problem. While googled i read about JSONDecoder solution but didnt understand how to apply it for my problem. Also i found a tip with creating empty dictionary and appending necessary data into it with for loop but i also faced with problems while tried to implement it and i think that solution with for loop and append even if help me inappropriate to solve this kind of frequent problem. I hope that in python must be more convinience and pythonic solution. I will aporeciate all advices and guidance. Thank in advance

Comment: Your file is not valid JSON, therefore, it cannot be parsed as JSON. What you are working with is JSON lines, essentially, a newline delimited file of valid JSON objects. So you can loop through each line and use the json parser for each line, `for line in f: json.loads(line)`

Comment: If you want to materialize a list of these objects, you could use a simple on-liner: `data = list(map(json.loads, f))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the same error

Comment: No, it does not give any error, at least not with the data you've provided. In any case, I've explained to you your fundamental problem, which is that you are trying to parse a file that isn't valid JSON with a JSON parser.